# How to retain only unique values in each row for a data frame

Tags: r

How to retain only unique values in each row for a data frame
input is as below:

```
1 1 2 3 4 1 6 7 8
2 2 5 5 7 8 9 0 0
6 6 6 6 5 1 2 3 4
```

Output would be as below

```
1 2 3 4 6 7 8
2 5 7 8 9
6 5 1 2 3 4
```

`plyr`, `unique` i tried, but it retains the unique values in complete data set

Comment: Dataframes can't have different numbers of values in each row, how would your expected output work in a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` or `lapply` to accomplish it .

```
#supposing your data.frame is called 'df'

sapply(df, unique)
#$x1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 6 7 8
#
#$x2
#[1] 2 5 7 8 9 0
#
#$x3
#[1] 6 5 1 2 3 4
```

or

```
lapply(df, unique)
#$x1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 6 7 8
#
#$x2
#[1] 2 5 7 8 9 0
#
#$x3
#[1] 6 5 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Imagine D is your data.frame object
  apply(D,1, function(x) rle(x)$values)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A=apply(dat,1,unique)
data.frame(t(sapply(A,`length<-`,max(lengths(A)))))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1  1  2  3  4  6  7  8
2  2  5  7  8  9  0 NA
3  6  5  1  2  3  4 NA
```